# Tag for emergency room (ER)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, Medical Sciences SE has [emergency-room-er](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency-room-er). As I mentioned [before](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1203/12704), I believe that synonyms should be made tag *synonyms*, rather than be included in the tag *name* itself.

Hence, I propose that the tag be renamed [emergency-room](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency-room) with synonym [er](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/er).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented as suggested in the question.